# While JavaScript File Reader With Pushing Data to Global Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have posted code below and trying to upload text files:
Problem is to store data in JavaScript array, ifileData always returns blank/null values.

```
<input type="file" name="ic-files[]" class="ic-input" multiple="true" />
<input type="file" name="ic-files[]" class="ic-input" multiple="true" />
<input type="file" name="ic-files[]" class="ic-input" multiple="true" />
<input type="file" name="ic-files[]" class="ic-input" multiple="true" />

<script>
var ifileData = new Array();
$(document).on('click','#start', function()
{
    $('.ic-input').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() != "")
        {
           var inCorrectFile = $(this).get(0).files;
           for (var i = 0; i < inCorrectFile.length; i++) 
            {
                var reader = new FileReader(); 
                reader.onload = function(e) 
                {
                    /* Temp Object */
                    var ipfileData = {};

                    var fileContent = this.result;
                    ipfileData['data'] = fileContent;

                    ifileData.push(ipfileData);
                }
                reader.readAsText(inCorrectFile[i], "UTF-8"); 
            }
        }
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(ifileData));
});
</script>
```

also i've posted code to https://jsfiddle.net/3aexs7wp/3/

Comment: You seem to be attempting to use an asynchronous method in a synchronous way. You will need to wait for the _load_ event (on the _FileReader_) to have fired before trying to access `ifileData`

Comment: Also note that for the same reason, the `for` loop cannot guarantee the order of items in `ifileData`. e.g. index `3` may finish before indices `1` and `2`, meaning you end up with `[3, 1, 2, 4]`

Comment: yes, you are right but if ordering change there is no any problem for this script. @PaulS.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `change` event for `click` event ; adjusting delegated selector to `.ic-input`

```js
var ifileData = new Array();
$(document).on('change', '.ic-input', function() {
  $('.ic-input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      var inCorrectFile = $(this).get(0).files;
      for (var i = 0; i < inCorrectFile.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          /* Temp Object */
          var ipfileData = {};

          var fileContent = this.result;
          ipfileData['data'] = fileContent;

          ifileData.push(ipfileData);
          console.log(ifileData)
        }
        reader.readAsText(inCorrectFile[i], "UTF-8");
      }
    }
  });
  // alert(JSON.stringify(ifileData));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="file" name="ic-files[]" class="ic-input" multiple="true" />
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3aexs7wp/4/